# Snowflake Seems to Auto-Cast VARCHAR to NUMERIC for Insert into VARCHAR Field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When trying to insert data into a Snowflake table, it appears that the presumed type of improperly cast input values may override the data type supplied by the table creation command.  For example, given a table created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE vctable (
    itemA VARCHAR(8),
    itemB VARCHAR(8)
);
```

The following command fails:

```
INSERT INTO vctable (itemA, itemB) VALUES ('hi','ho'), (1,2);
ERROR: Numeric value 'hi' is not recognized
```

I expect this insert to fail because the *second* record's data types do not match the table definition (as expected, if I cast the second record's elements as strings, the insert is successful).  But the error says that the failure is because Snowflake cannot convert 'hi', which is in the first (correctly formatted) record, to a numeric value.  It's as if, having surveyed the inputs, Snowflake has decided to override the data types declared in the table.  Why is Snowflake trying to convert the strings *away* from the table definition?

Incidentally, if the insert is broken into two separate statements, both work.

Comment: Probably worth opening a ticket with Snowflake Support as a bug.  This is likely related to how the optimizer is evaluating the order of operations, but it doesn't really matter why...it really just shouldn't be throwing the error at all.  I would expect the numbers to be implicitly cast to varchar in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of execution.

```sql
INSERT INTO vctable (itemA, itemB) VALUES ('hi','ho'), (1,2);
```

is kind of equivalent to

```sql
INSERT INTO vctable
select 'hi','ho'
union all select 1, 2;
```

which has the subquery:

```sql
select 'hi','ho'
union select 1, 2
```

which fails with `Numeric value 'hi' is not recognized`.

Then you'll note that even this fails:

```sql
select $1::varchar, $2::varchar
from VALUES ('hi','ho'), (1, 2);
```

It's too late even for a cast at the `select` level, because `values()` needs to run first.

Comment: could u plz explain why simple insert gets converted to some weird 'select ... union ...'? A very strange and implicit behavior. I didn't know that.
Also could u share what's your suggested solution to insert multiple rows here?

Comment: Hi @c00p3r.web - please ask a new question with an explicit example so we can work with that

Answer (score 0):

You must convert numeric values to string at the VALUES clause level, try this one:

```
INSERT INTO vctable (itemA, itemB) VALUES ('hi','ho'), (1::string,2::string);
```